# Equivalence of definitions of $C^k(\overline U)$

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-geometry, derivatives, banach-spaces

let $U$ be an open set of $\mathbb{R}^n$, that contains at least some open set.

In Evans book we find the definition

$$C^k(\overline U)=\{f \in C^k(U): D^\alpha f \text{ is uniformly continuous on bounded subsets of} U, \text{ for all }|\alpha|\leq k \}$$

it is easy to show that this is equivalent to

$$ C^k(\overline U) = \{f\in C^k(U)| D^\alpha f \text{ can be extended continuously on } \overline U, \text{ for all } \}$$

In differential geometry the definition

$$ C^k(\overline U) = \{f|_{\overline U} \colon \exists O\supset \overline U \text{ such that } f\in C^k(O)\}$$

Is it obvious that the first two definitions are equivalent to the last one?

Edit: Or was this identity first shown in Whitney's extension theorem?

Edit 2:
Conisdering Guiseppe Negro's comment: Since the last definition is used in differential geometry, is it true that those definitions are equivalent when the set $\overline U$ is a manifold or manifold with boundary?

Comment: They are not equivalent, the second condition being stronger. If a domain is not sufficiently smooth, a function defined in it can be smooth without being the restriction of a global smooth function. This can be a major nuisance, especially (AFAIK) in the theory of Sobolev spaces.

Comment: You are right, in the case of Sobolev spaces this turns awkward. Somehow I had in mind that Whitney's extension theorem http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitney_extension_theorem deals with this case. Probably for arbitrary closed domains the "compatibility condition" is violated

Comment: I am sorry that I cannot contribute more to this and the other thread (the one with the bounty on it). Anyway, the standard example of a domain for which the second definition yields a strictly smaller space is due to Lebesgue and it is the two-dimensional domain $$ \{-1\le x \le 1,\ -1\le y \le 1\ :\ \lvert y \rvert \ge \begin{cases} e^{-1\x}, & x>0 \\ 0, x \le 0 \end{cases}\}.$$(It is a square with an entering sharp cusp). The function $$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}x^2 & x> 0,\ y>0 \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$ is $C^1$ in the interior of this domain [...]

Comment: [...] and can also be extended to the boundary together with its first derivative. However, it cannot be the restriction of any global $C^1$ function, because such a function wouldn't be Lipschitz continuous in a neighborhood of the origin.

Comment: Hope this helps. Anyway, the standard resource for questions of this kind in the category of Sobolev spaces is AFAIK the book by Adams.

Comment: Regarding edit 2: Yes, those definitions are equivalent if you have a smooth enough boundary, for in that case you can construct an extension operator by performing a reflection locally at any point of the boundary. This is surely explained in Adams's book, in the chapter on "extension theorems". Constructing an extension operator for $C^k$ functions is the first step towards the construction of an extension operator for Sobolev functions.

Comment: Hey thanks alot. I just found in the book of Gilbarg Trudinger almost the same example but your comment taught me how to interpret it correctly. In the book of Adams, a $C^1$ extension is only shown for $C^1$ boundary. For Lipschitz boundary (considering the proof in Alt's Book (Funktionalanalysis)) one only obtains a $C^{0,1}$ extension. Again, this won't be a counter example but it indicates that higher regularity can't be obtained. Maybe your example could even work, if one replaces the cusp by that indicated by the picture in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity

Comment: You mean a "Pac-Man" domain, I guess. You might try. I am sure that there exist functions which are $C^1$ on a Pac-Man and that cannot be obtained as the restriction of any global $C^1$ functions. Unfortunately I don't know any explicit example. I am afraid that the same $f$ as before won't work, but maybe it can be adapted somehow.

Comment: Somewhat related: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/376441/8157

Comment: Hey, I didn't think directly of a Pac-Man domain. You could change the paths forming pacmans mouth by an oscillationg function (see the wikipedia link and the double cone example). But maybe your example already works. But I think that isolated corners are not a too big problem. On cubes a simple reflection could work. And if i remember correctly, the reflection technique also works on  "regular" polygons

Comment: Maybe your pacman domain has the advantage that the cusps points to the inside and hence we won't have a regular domain. One could consider the set $\{x^2+y^2\leq 1 | <\leq |x|\}$. And we choose the functions $f(x,y)=\text{sign}(x)\, y\,\text{sign}_+(y)$. The functions is $C^1$ inside the domain. However, from general theory one can find a Lipschitz extenstion (and even geometrically one can see that such an extension exist).  However, I don't know how to prove that $f$ can't be the restricion of a $C^1$ function.

Comment: It seems that this can't provide a counter example. If we straighten the cusp by bending, we obtain a half space. The bending operation can be performed smoothly (if i remember correctly). On the half space, I obtain a smooth extension of the function.

Comment: to close this: as it is pointed out here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/727364/is-it-possible-to-extend-a-c1-function-smoothly-from-any-lipschitz-domain/744260?noredirect=1#comment1552572_744260 the definitions are equivalent if $U$ is quasiconvex