# Is it possible to extend a $C^1$-function smoothly from any Lipschitz domain?

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request

If $\Omega$ is a cube in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $f\in C^1(\overline\Omega)$. By reflection one can extend such a function to all of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and the extenstion is in $C^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$. 
If $\Omega$ is a polygon, has piecewise $C^1$ boundary (so edges and corneres are not to wild) or is a convex set this still seems to be possible. 
Can this be extended to arbitrary Lipschitz domains?

Are there examples and or references for these cases (starting from polygons)?

Comment: How exactly do you define $C^1(\overline \Omega)$? A standard tool in this business is the Whitney extension theorem, e.g., [Theorem 2.1 here](http://www.pitt.edu/~hajlasz/Notatki/Analysis%204.pdf).

Comment: $f$ and all its partial derivatives are continuous up to the boundary. So my problem when it comes to Whitney's theorem is: Can I guarantee (with my assumption) that the limit (in the theorem) has this uniformity property? If the domain is $C^1$, I will obtain this. But for mere Lipschitz boundary this is not so clear, isn't it? Otherwise, one could always extend any $C^1$-function from Lipschitz domains which sounds a bit odd. You also might check the comment of Giuseppe Negro here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/723686/equivalence-of-definitions-of-ck-overline-u

Comment: What about the identity function on the 1-cube $[0,1]$? If you extended it by reflection, you get on $[-1,1]$ the absolute value which is not $C^1$.

Comment: @Thibaut Dumont There are different kinds of reflection, besides the one you have in mind. Some preserve some smoothness.

Comment: You need arbitrarily close points in the domain to be connected by arbitrarily short curves. If this is the case, then the requirements of Whitney's theorem will be satisfied.

Comment: @George Lowther, can you provide a reference for this? in Alt's "Funktionalanalysis" there is a theorem (§ 8.4) that says the following: In a Lipschitz domain any there is a constant $C_\Omega$ depending on the domain such that for any two points $x_0,x_1\in \Omega$ there is a (smooth) curve $\gamma $connecting the two points inside of $\Omega$ such that its length is estimated by $L(\gamma)\leq C_\Omega |x_1-x_0|$.  However, considering your comment, this would imply that for Lipschtz domains there is is always a $C^1$ extenstion on $\mathbb{R}^n$, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Quickbeam2k1: Sorry, I made a mistake there, and what you state is exactly what you need. The conditions for Whitney's theorem will be satisfied as long as there is a $C > 0$ such that any two points $x,y$ in the domain are joined (in the domain) by a curve of length no more than $C\lvert x-y\rvert$. Just requiring that the length is arbitrarily small for arbitrarily small $\lvert x-y\rvert$ is not enough.

Comment: ...but it still does imply that there is always an extension for Lipschitz domains.

Comment: @George Lowther. That's astonishing and I never found something where this was pointed out. And even my boss believes, that there is no $C^1$-extension for Lipschitz domains. Could you provide a reference (or if it is immediate a simple proof?) and I could award you the bounty.

Comment: @cheapeffectivedietpills Any reference for a concrete example? I guess these reflections are not simply symmetries

Comment: To extend a function $f$ from $[0,1]$ to $[-1,1]$, you can define the extension on $[-1,0)$ by $\tilde f(t)=2 f(0) - f(-t)$

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As George Lowther pointed out, such an extension is possible for any quasiconvex domains (in particular, for any Lipschitz domain). This is the main result in a short paper by Whitney from 1934:

> Whitney, Hassler. *Functions differentiable on the boundaries of regions.* Ann. of Math. (2) 35 (1934), no. 3, 482–485.

[image: whitney]

Property P is what we now call quasiconvexity:

[image: quasiconvexity]

This result, and many later developments, are presented in section 2.5 of  the book

> Brudnyi, Alexander; Brudnyi, Yuri. *Methods of geometric analysis in extension and trace problems*. Volume 1. Monographs in Mathematics, 102. Birkhäuser/Springer Basel AG, Basel, 2012.

Comment: thank you so much, is there a way to award George Lowther and you some extra reputation?

Comment: @Quick Don't worry about it. If you feel like doing something about this thread, please change the title into something less likely to mislead casual readers into thinking the result is false.

Comment: corrected it :)

Comment: Just for clearification: In the article and also in the book the class $C^m$ is merely the class of functions such that the $m^{th}$-partial derivatives are considered (i.e. a "homogeneous" semi norm is taken into account). How, e.g. in the case $m=1$ can one return to the full case? Or are the extensions for $m=0$ and $m=1$ "compatible"?

Comment: @Quick. Continuity of partial derivatives implies the function itself is continuous. So, continuity of m-th derivatives implies continuity of lower orders too. If boundedness becomes an issue, multiply by a smooth cutoff function.

Comment: oh crap :) this is like first course: differentiability implies continuity :) lol thanks :)

Comment: @user127096 Does this hold also for $m=\infty$, to your knowledge?