# The regularity for elliptic problems

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, regularity-theory-of-pdes, elliptic-equations, fractional-sobolev-spaces

Assume $$\Omega=\{(r,\theta):0<r<1,0<\theta<\omega\},$$
here $\omega>\pi$. That means $\Omega$ is not a convex domain. We solve Laplace problem in $\Omega$. Solution $u$ will behave like
$$u\sim r^{\pi/\omega}\sin(\dfrac{\pi}{\omega}\theta).$$
I know a conclusion that $u\in H^{1+\pi /\omega-\epsilon}$, here $\epsilon>0$. But I don't know how to prove it, or if there are some clear references?

Comment: Taking derivative, then integrate in polar coordinates.

Comment: @Shuhao Cao Thank you for your help. I don't know how to integrate for the fractional part.

Comment: @Shuhao Cao  I think I finish it. Thank you.